# Как в своем профиле изменить описание?

Tags: поддержка

Как мне в своем профиле изменить свое описание?

Comment: Там всего три Таба, щёлкните по последнему и готово. Там все и меняйте.

Comment: @VladSpirin, по первому же?

Comment: @Qwertiy Так вроде 3-й это "Править"?????

Comment: @VladSpirin, хм.. На первом есть ссылка "нажмите для редактирования". Как оказалось, она как раз ведёт на третий :)

Comment: @Qwertiy А точно, так тоже можно :)